# Strange fragment behaviour - empty container in view hierarchy after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I encountered very strange problem with fragments. In my case I have fragment which is placed inside activity. It has two type of layout:
layout - with Frame Layout with `list_container` id
layout-land - with two Layout: `list_container` and `detail_container`.

When user enters activity in portrait mode he sees `TestListFragment`. When he clicks one of the list element `TestDetailFragment` is added to backstack.
Next, when user rotates screen `TestDetailFragment` is removed from backstack and placed inside layout with id `detail_container`. How strange part appears, when inspecting view hierarchy there are two list_containers (one is empty and is over the rest of the content causing view overlap). `onActivityCreated` in `TestFragment` is triggered twice.

I'm including hierarchy view and screens:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXec3.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CJNT.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqZyy.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3EHy.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKNvU.png

Source code:

- Activity with fragments: http://pastebin.com/2vAqQYgw
- Activity layout: http://pastebin.com/iEawVBCx
- TestFragment layout: http://pastebin.com/z5MZ5eR9
- TestFragment layout-land: http://pastebin.com/RJHYRinM

Is this normal behavior? How to get rid of this layout?

Comment: You are not using nested fragments properly. You need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` of `TestFragment` to add its nested fragments, and you are using `getSupportFragmentManager()` of the activity instead. I would also make my decisions to add fragments based upon whether fragments exist, not whether `savedInstanceState` is `null`. I am uncertain if either of those are directly related to your problem, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare replacing `getSupportFragmentManager()` with `getChildFragmentManager()` solved my problem. Thanks. Can you post this comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you nest fragments (i.e., have a fragment host a fragment), the child fragments need to be set up either by:

- having the parent fragment inflate a layout containing `<fragment>` tags
- having the parent fragment use `getChildFragmentManager()` when executing a `FragmentTransaction` to add the child fragments

In this case, the code in the question is using `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`, not `getChildFragmentManager()`.

To be honest, I cannot completely understand how this resulted in the cited symptoms, but according to the comments on the question, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

When **Android** detect *rotation* it destroyes the running activity and create a new one, so if you have a behaviour on `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` of the activity, keep in mind that. Take care also for `Fragment` that has a further event to manage and is related on the attached Activity `onAttach()`